C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\cctSSakm.o:test.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `get_string' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I see the error
c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\cc61L1BV.o:test.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string ("what is your name?: ")
        ;printf("hello world%s", name);
}

when typing: make test it's showing me this:
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c:2:10: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <cs50.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1


I’m voting to close this question because this appears to mix two different problems (title is a link error, body a missing header). Either would be a duplicate, but as it stands it's unclear what this would be a duplicate of.

It can't find the CS50 library. Questions for how to install the CS50 specific library are probably better asked at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

What are you doing to get the first error message? You must be doing different things to get these different error messages. What does the CS50 learning material tell about installing and using the library? Did you follow it?

You will need to have the missing header and library files installed.
The source is available from: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/
But I had a look at the source and it looked like it was just supporting Linux and Mac.
Fortunately only some changes in Makefile were needed to build and install properly on Windows using MinGW-w64.
I have submitted the required changes here: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/pull/333
To build cs50 I used MSYS2 shell and ran the following command in the extracted (and patched) source folder (replace /somepath with a real location):
make install CC=${CC:-gcc} DESTDIR=/somepath

Then to use in your application you will need to add compiler flag -I/somepath/include and linker flags -L/somepath/lib -lcs50.
